# How can I add shadow in my Materialbutton

Tags: android

I have applied elevation to my materialbutton but there is still no shadow showing beneath the button

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:textColor="@color/violet"
                android:text="9"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>
```

I tried increasing the elevation but there is no effect.

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap it with "CardView" :

```
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:cardCornerRadius="40dp" <!-- Adjust this value for rounded corners -->
    app:cardElevation="4dp"> <!-- Adjust this value for shadow depth -->

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:textColor="@color/violet"
        android:text="9"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```